# How to make two Template matching for two images with maximum similarity?

Tags: python, opencv, templates, image-processing, imagemagick

There are various way to crop image also there are various ways to match template using opencv.

But is there any way to use this together to get the image with maximum similarity? such that the two images are over lap with minimum difference.

code for template making :

```py
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    path = './Image_1.png'
    org = cv2.imread(path)
    img = cv2.imread(path)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

    contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

    for cnt in contours:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
        
        # print (len(approx))
        if len(approx)==5:
            # print "pentagon"
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,255,-1)
        elif len(approx)==3:
            # print "triangle"
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),-1)
        elif len(approx)==4:
            # print "square"
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),-1)
        elif len(approx) == 9:
            # print "half-circle"
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255,255,0),-1)
        elif len(approx) > 15:
            # print "circle"
            cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,255),-1)

        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        roi_1 = org[y:y+h, x:x+w]                                                                        # crop image
        # dst = cv2.create(roi.size(), CV_8UC3)

    print (roi_1.shape)

    cv2.imwrite('./test/Image_crop.jpg', roi_1)                                                          # color org. image
    # cv2.imshow('img',roi)
    # cv2.imshow('img_1',img)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imshow('img_2',roi_1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

after making two templates:

code for template Matching:

```py
        import numpy as np
        import cv2
         
        image = cv2.imread('./Image_1.png')
        template = cv2.imread('./Image_2.jpg')
         
        # resize images
        image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
        template = cv2.resize(template, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
         
        # Convert to grayscale
        imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         
        # Find template
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(imageGray,templateGray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        top_left = max_loc
        h,w = templateGray.shape
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
        cv2.rectangle(image,top_left, bottom_right,(0,0,255),1)
         
        # Show result
        cv2.imshow("Template", template)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.imshow("Result", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

this is the code to make the template and then matching those, but what if we want to make two same template with 99% of match of same object captured using camera.

**any solution  to make template for two images of same object with maximum similarity ?**

In other works I want to make Template which are identical to each other which are also same?

Image 1:
[image: Image 1]

Image 2:
[image: Image 2]

Accepted Output:
[image: Accepted output]

output after difference:
[image: output]

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps if you provide a link to two of your images, we can see what you  are trying to do and suggest some solutions.

Comment: @fmw42 added sample images.

Comment: In Imagemagick, if you have to images where one is smaller than the other, you can do a subimage-search using compare to shift one image to find its best alignment with the other. You can do that with OpenCV as well. So perhaps crop one of your images so that it has enough room to shift to get a best match with the other one. Or pad one image with your background color so that it is larger. Then do the template matching to find the best shift location for he matches. You might also crop off the black part.